# Input Redirection - Cin not working with command line

Tags: c++, input, cin, argv, argc

I am tasked to write a simple program that reads in a file, and determines if the characters '(' '[' and '{' and "balanced". Meaning, There is a matching closing bracket/brace/parentheses for each opening one.

I am having trouble with the input. We are to use input redirection, not an iostream object, taking advantage of the command line. We utilize a makefile and when I run the executable it tells me 2 errors: not using argc and argv[].

```
    struct Contents {
    int numP;
    int numS;
    int numC;
};

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {
    char word;
    Contents c;
 
    
    while(cin >> word) {
        if(word == '{' || word == '}') {
            c.numC++;
        }
        if(word == '(' || word == ')') {
            c.numP++;
        }
        if(word == '[' || word == ']') {
            c.numS++;
        }
    }
    
    if(c.numC % 2 == 0 || c.numP % 2 == 0 || c.numS % 2 == 0) {
        cout << "Balanced" << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Not Balanced" << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

What am I missing here to make the file redirection input work? When I run this in XCode I just enter a bunch of values and it never ends. I can't seem to do the input right.

Thank you!

Comment: Your code compiles fine but it has a logic problem in the while loop, have you figured out how you are going to exit the loop?

Comment: I am not sure how to end the input if I am reading in from a file. Since I am not allowed to use an iostream object and must use the command line to have the file read by cin, I don't get how to end the input

Comment: can you show how you are reading from the file? You can look at the file endings to break out from the loop.

Comment: Using redirection your command line would be `./program < input_file`

Comment: Note that your code will think that `{{{{` is balanced and you may need to rethink your algorithm once you're successfully reading input. And I don't know if you're supposed to consider `({)}` balanced or not, but if that's supposed to count as unbalanced you should keep that test case in mind too.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I understand how cin works with redirection now. I will have to change around the algorithm to see if something is "balanced" or not

Answer (score 1):

You need to break out of the while loop, if you are reading from a file then your code should work as it is. I have just made a small change to the logic when checking whether it is balanced or not.

```
   int main() {
       char word;
       Contents c;

       while (cin >> word) {    
           if (word == '{' || word == '}') {
               c.numC++;
           }
           if (word == '(' || word == ')') {
               c.numP++;
           }
           if (word == '[' || word == ']') {
               c.numS++;
           }
       }
       // Edited here: Check using and instead of or.
       if (c.numC % 2 == 0 && c.numP % 2 == 0 && c.numS % 2 == 0) {
           cout << "Balanced" << endl;
       } else {
           cout << "Not Balanced" << endl;
       }

       return 0;
   }
```

Update:

I have tested the code, so here is the output.

[image]

Here is the output. You can redirect the input to any file and it will scan the file until it reaches EOF.

Comment: See [Why !.eof() inside a loop condition is always wrong.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/9254539)

Comment: Oh,  I have updated my answer. It was the same code that he posted in the question, with just the logic changed from `||` or `&&` when checking.

Comment: Thank you this helped a lot! I still need to change my algorithm around but I can handle that part.